# How to call another intent without losing previous data?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have 2 pages in  my application. From Page A I am calling Page B. On page B I have a ListView which is filled by users. Now when User clicks on Back Button of the phone he comes  back to Page A. But when he clicks menu and select Add Items again, it opens Page B but my ListView is empty. How can I get back to Page B without losing data in ListView?

Comment: Please provide code that you use. At the first look, you can use sqlite database to save data from list, and restore it when user back to page B.

Comment: @Pepelac this is how I call my intent 
Intent AddItems = new Intent(ClaimManagementActivity.this,AddItems.class);
  ClaimManagementActivity.this.startActivity(AddItems);

Answer (score 1):

Override the `onBackPressed` in page B, and save your data some where..
then in the `onStart` of page B reload the data..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save and load the data in a list

I.e

```
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
 SharedPreferences settingsActivity = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settingsActivity.edit();
 prefEditor.putString(LISTFROMB, savedItems);
 prefEditor.commit();
   }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

And then load it in A like :

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple);

    // Find the ListView resource.
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    SharedPreferences settingsActivity = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedItems = settingsActivity.getString(LISTFROMB, "");
    selectedItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(savedItems.split(",")));

    [CALL YOUR ADAPTER HERE WITH THE SELECTED ITEMS LIST]

}
```

Comment: Hi @fasheikh, I dont want to retrieve anything from Page B in Page A. I just want my list view to be filled as it was when I left the page. I think I can do it if I can save my SimpleAdapter some how. Is it possible?

Comment: oh sorry, then add the onCreate to Page B

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to use the `SharedPreferences`:

```
public void onStop(Bundle bundle)
{
   SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
   editor.putBoolean("myBool",true);
   //Continue saving all the data you need to recreate the listView
}
```

Then when you restart the activity, you can reload the preferences in the OnCreate() method like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Retrieve the saved values.
    boolean myBool = mySharedPreferences.getBoolean("myBool");
    //Recreate the ListView here
}
```

It might not be the cleanest way to do so. But since `onSavedInstanceState` can't be used in your case, it will have to do :)

Comment: Can you please tell me if I can save my SimpleAdapter some how? Then it will be easy to get my listview back.

Comment: You can try to subclass the SimpleAdapter and make it implement the Parcelable interface. Then you can use `editor.putParcelable()`. See this link for an example how to do this: http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/06/parcelable-how-to-do-that-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I solved the problem just by declaring the ArrayList in Page A. So now when I go back to Page B the source of the ListView is in Page A so easy to load it back.

Don't know if this approach is wrong. Please leave your comment if you think this shouldn't be done.